# C# HttpClient Server rejects Multipart Content Type Calls

Tags: c#, apache, ssl

We decide to move our API to a server with SSL, before that everything works fine, but since we change to the server with SSL the calls with content-type: multipart/form-data just dont work (403 forbidden), the ones with Content-Type: application/json works fine, i think is a problem with the server/Apache but i dont want to stay arms crossed while the one in the team who has the access to that tries to solve it, so i want to discard any problem with my code
HttpClient call

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            if (EmailText.Text.Contains("@") && EmailText.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                content.Add(new StringContent(EmailText.Text), "\"email\"");
            }
            else
            {
                content.Add(new StringContent(EmailText.Text), "\"username\"");
            }

            content.Add(new StringContent(PasswordText.Password), "\"password\"");
            var hand = new HttpClientHandler();
            hand.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            hand.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(hand))
            {
                var Uri = new Uri("https://kuwai.tech");
                httpClient.BaseAddress = Uri;
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("appName","MetaPrinter");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("latitude", SettingsHelper.Settings.APISettings.Latitude);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("longitude", SettingsHelper.Settings.APISettings.Longitude);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("hostname", SettingsHelper.Settings.APISettings.IP);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("hostType", "PC");
                var httpResponse = httpClient.PostAsync("/apis/" + api + "/auth/login", content);
                responseContent = await httpResponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Result result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(responseContent);
```

i think everything in my code its ok, but i want to make sure, as i said before using the SSL server it worked well.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: As with most of these types of questions, you can easily use fiddler to compare the 2 different versions of the post. Any differences will stick out instantly

Comment: @TheGeneral they are the same, i already use fiddler, the only difference is that the server with SSL returns a 403

Comment: Then i guess you already know the answer